# Histórico com últimos links acessados

Tags: javascript

Recentemente vi um site com um sistema um tanto legal, ele mostrava um histórico com todos os links que o visitante havia clicado, mostrando imagens e títulos da página, e claramente usava cookies do navegador.
Pesquisei algumas funções e acabei chegando a uma função window.history, mais não foi possível chegar ao resultado esperado, alguém tem uma noção de como fazer ?

Comment: Aí vai necessitar de um sistema um pouco complexo que sub pra primeira posição o item mais atual e abaixe os anteriores corretamente e não repita os itens.
Eu postei a resposta, mas não tem como ser preciso sem que o @Gabriel tenha alguma base de conhecimento sobre Jscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde me recordo `window.history` nos navegadores modernos foi restringido por segurança, como você mesmo disse, a solução seriam cookies, mas se você não vai salvar nada no servidor também pode usar `localStorage` (Limitado à 5Mbs).

No exemplo vou fazer um limite de 7 históricos.

Para salvar o link que estiver navegando no momento:

```
localStorage.setItem("URL_1",window.location.toString());
```

Eu não costumo fazer sistemas do zero, mas pra esse caso vou deixar pronto e espero que entenda e aproveito, neste exemplo eu apenas coloquei pra salvar a URL do histórico:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TÍTULO</title>
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="https://url_da_imagem" />
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  showHistory();
};

function saveHistory(){
    var count_h = localStorage.length;
    if(count_h != 7){
        /* INICIAR LISTAGEM EM BRANCO */
        localStorage.setItem('URL_0',window.location.toString());
        localStorage.setItem('URL_1',"");
        localStorage.setItem('URL_2',"");
        localStorage.setItem('URL_3',"");
        localStorage.setItem('URL_4',"");
        localStorage.setItem('URL_5',"");
        localStorage.setItem('URL_6',"");
    }else{
        /* Subir ITEM atual e abaixar mais antigos */
        for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            var save = true;
            if(window.location.toString() == localStorage.getItem("URL_"+j)){
                save = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(save == true){
            localStorage.setItem('URL_6',localStorage.getItem("URL_5"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_5',localStorage.getItem("URL_4"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_4',localStorage.getItem("URL_3"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_3',localStorage.getItem("URL_2"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_2',localStorage.getItem("URL_1"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_1',localStorage.getItem("URL_0"));
            localStorage.setItem('URL_0',window.location.toString());

        }
    }
}

var empty;
function showHistory(){
    saveHistory();
    var list = document.getElementById('history');
    empty = list.innerHTML;
    var count_h = localStorage.length;
    list.innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < count_h; i++) {
        var tmp_key = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
        console.log(tmp_key);
        if(tmp_key != ""){
            list.innerHTML += "<li>"+tmp_key+"</li>";
        }
    }
}

function clearHistory(){
    document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = empty;
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('URL_0',window.location.toString());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="?A01">A01</a> | 
<a href="?B02">B02</a> | 
<a href="?C03">C03</a> | 
<a href="?D04">D04</a> | 
<a href="?E05">E05</a> | 
<a href="?F06">F06</a> | 
<a href="?G07">G07</a> | 
<a href="?H08">H08</a> | 
<a href="?I09">I09</a> | 
<a href="?J10">J10</a> | 
<a href="?K11">K11</a> | 
<a href="?L12">L12</a>
</ul><br /><p onclick="clearHistory()">[Limpar Histórico]</p>
<ul id="history">
<li>-- SEM HISTÓRICO --</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Para salvar imagem e título aconselho estudar `ElementsByTagName`, por exemplo, pra pegar a imagem da meta tag `OpenGraph` de imagem:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['og:image'].content
```

Agora pra poder pegar os dados dessas meta tags tem que adicionar o atributo `name` com o mesmo termo usado no `property`, então seguindo o exemplo, de:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://url_da_imagem" />
```

Ficará assim:

```
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="https://url_da_imagem" />
```